# How does Entity Framework Extended batch Update method deal with default values?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-extended

I'm using Entity Framework Extended to perform a batch update just like the example below from its official documentation (https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Batch-Update-and-Delete):

```
//update all tasks with status of 1 to status of 2
context.Tasks
.Where(t => t.StatusId == 1)
.Update(t => new Task { StatusId = 2 });
```

It works, but I'd like to know the inner workings. How does it deal with the default values of the `Task` object. Let's say it has a property called `MyProperty` which is an `int` that defaults to `0`. When a `Task` object is initialized, it's `MyProperty` value will have the default value of `0`. How does Entity Framework Extended distinguish between `MyProperty` having the *default value of 0*, or if I'm trying to set `MyProperty` of all matched objects to their default value of 0, e.g. `new Task { StatusId = 2 , MyProperty = 0}` as the created `Task` object will be exactly the same in each case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass this:

```
.Update(t => new Task { StatusId = 2 });
```

You are not creating a `Task` object at all. You are passing in an expression which the batch updater is parsing (and not executing at all). The `new Task { StatusId = 2 }` is never executed.

Comment: Oh, it's part of the expression then, not an object. Now it makes sense.

Comment: Yes, that's why you pass in a lambda (`t =>`), and not just a `new Task { ... }`